# Passing JSONArray via Apache httpclient

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to pass an array of objects with several attributes to a php webservice using `apache httpclient` but I'm not sure how. I have tried to use `JSON` to encode the array and objects. The below methods create the `JSON` objects and then add them to a `JSONArray`:

```
  createArray(){

     JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
 }


 public void addObj(long var1, int var2, int var3, int var4){

    JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("one:", var1);
        obj.put("two:", var2);
        obj.put("three:", var3);
        obj.put("four:", var4);
        arr.put(obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Next I have a class to pass my data to my webservice:

```
public class Upload {

private String userID = null;
private String password = null;
private String email = null;

Upload(String userID, String password, String email){
    this.userID = userID;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}

public void uploadData(JSONArray arr) throws Exception{

    //HTTP POST Service
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();         
        URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.mysite.com")
        .setPath("/mypage.php")
        .build();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));

        String encoding = new String(
                 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
                    (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(userID + ":" + password))
                  );
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        System.out.println(response);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        String str = "";
        if (httpEntity != null) {
            str = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I thought I might be able to simply pass the `JSONArray` as a parameter same as before by doing:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JsonArray", arr));
```

But this doesn't work since add only seems to accept strings. How can I do it?

Comment: does not compile, arr is not defined in this scope

Comment: If I use arr.toString is there a simple method to transform it back on the php side so that I can manipulate it like an array of objects still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonObject has a `toString` method that gives you a string representation of the json object. I don't think you need a JsonArray, but in case you need just put it inside a JSONObject.
The point is HTTP only understands strings. 
Another point is, in case your json is large, it is better to upload it rather than passing as a parameter.

Comment: Could you explain why I don't need a JSONArray please? Also could you give an example of how to use upload in this context? I've only seen it used for files?

Comment: Well in the example, you just added one single object to the array. So  the array is redundant as there is only one element in it.

Comment: Ah no sorry not clear, that method is called multiple times before the upload class is instantiated so the JSONArray would usually contain multiple JSONObjects.

Comment: In that case add the array to a new json object.

Comment: Okay thanks I'm trying that - in terms of upload vs parameter how large is large? Anything else I should bear in mind?

Comment: That is tricky. It is a matter of taste and what you want to achieve. Usually JSON is attached as a file rather than a parameter. But technically you can just use a parameter. Keep in mind that there is usually a hard limit depending on the web server you use. For example Tomcat has a 2MB limit on post parameters.

Comment: I'm not expecting my JSON to be that large (saving a typical example in a text file gave me about 15kB) so parameter should be safe to use and less overhead than outputting to a file first and then retrieving it again?

Comment: You don't need to save and retrieve it. What I meant is add json as a payload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45126/discussion-between-db579-and-arash)

Comment: How would I reference the json object on the php side once I've passed it (as in your link)? I assumed $_POST['JSONContainerObject'] would work but I'm getting an undefined error.